# Django: Checkbox Onclick Event

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I want to make it so that if To be annouced is clicked then the form input for the release date disapears. How can I add an onclick to the checkbox of a form input?

Templates:

```
{{form.tba.label}}
{{form.tba}}

<p>{{form.release_date.label}} (not required)</p>
<div class="date_container">{{form.release_date}}</div>
```

forms:

```
tba = forms.BooleanField(label="Release date to be announced", widget=forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'form_input_bool'}), required=False)
release_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(attrs={'class': 'form_input_select_date'}, years=YEARS, empty_label="---"), required=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below javascript code:

```
var tba = document.getElementById('id_tba');
var release_date = document.getElementById('id_release_date');

if (tba.checked) {
   release_date.style.display = "none";
}
else {
   release_date.style.display = "block";
}
```